# Unable to publish Dialogflow bot despite brand verification

Tags: publish, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

***Current Scenario :  As per brand verification process before publishing Dialogflow bot on 
 google assistant, I have verified my ownership by connecting to the website for https://www.example.com/.***

I am unable to publish bot I tried few combination to make it work

- Invocation name : Example Bank
- Bank Display name :  Example Bank
- Website connected : https://www.example.com/
- **Error : Example Bank is reserved name. Kindly verify ownership**

2)

- Invocation name : Example
- Display name :  Example
- Website connected : https://www.example.com/
- **Error : Could not reserve Example because : App name has one word.**

None of the combination worked. How do I do it ?
if, I have only website to connect to.

Comment: You can contact the AoG support team: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted AoG support team. They verified from their end.